# Can Hard and Soft-IRQ for the same network-packet be executed on different CPU-Cores?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, x86, interrupt

Can Hard and Soft-IRQ for the same network-packet be executed on different CPU-Cores when network packets are processed on Linux x86_64 kernel 3.16?

- **Hard-IRQ raises Soft-IRQ**: http://she-devel.com/Chaiken_ELCE2016.pdf

  > Soft IRQs may run directly after the hard IRQ that raises them, or at
  > a later time in ksoftirqd.
- RSS raises **Soft-IRQ on the same CPU-Core as Hard-IRQ**: http://balodeamit.blogspot.ru/2013/10/receive-side-scaling-and-receive-packet.html

  > In case of multi queues (RSS), hardware interrupt will go to matching
  > CPU processor, and that processor will also be responsible for softIRQ
  > processing.
- In case of monoqueues, without RPS the Soft-IRQ processed on the same CPU-Core as Hard-IRQ, but **with RPS the Soft-IRQ processed on another CPU-Core than Hard-IRQ**: http://balodeamit.blogspot.ru/2013/10/receive-side-scaling-and-receive-packet.html

  > In case of monoqueues, the hardware interrupt generated is from single
  > queue and same CPU is also responisble for processing softIRQ. If RPS
  > is enabled on mono queue, the incoming packets are hashed, load is
  > distributed across multiple CPU processors.
- **RPS raises Soft-IRQ on the other CPU-Core than Hard-IRQ** and it increases the rate of inter-processor interrupts (IPIs): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt#Performance_issues

  > As a downside, RPS increases the rate of inter-processor interrupts
  > (IPIs).

---

Does it mean that:

- Ethernet-adapter (NIC) copy packet to the socket-buffer (mbuf) by using NIC-DMA and then NIC invoke **Hard-IRQ on CPU Core-N**
- Then code of this Hard-IRQ do nothing more than invoke **Soft-IRQ on the different CPU Core-M** by using RPS
- On this CPU Core-M the Soft-IRQ processes this packet by using TCP/IP-stack in kernel-space
- Then our Application by using `read(,buf,)` get the data from the socket-buffer (mbuf) to the our buffer in user-space on **CPU Core-K**

Is that correct?

Can Hard and Soft-IRQ for the same network-packet be executed on different cores when used RPS?

Comment: Note that the blog says "*There is no real need of RPS if you have RSS working.*", because they solve the same problem.  So if you have a good NIC, you probably want to disable RPS if it's enabled.  Hmm, unless all your throughput is for the same src/dst IP and port pair, in which case RSS sends it all to a single queue?

Comment: @Peter Cordes Hi. Some of NICs can be configured for hashing based on not only the src/dst, ip/port for RSS, but also on: Layer 2 dst addr, VLAN-tag,  Layer 3 protocol field) - look at `rx-flow-hash`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/ethtool.8.html  The main advantage of RPS is that it allows you to turn on RFS, and RFS is much more productive feature for the performance of network applications. if all 3 conditions are met: if NIC is good so has a good hash-function (1), packets distrubuted evenly across queues (2), and if there is no need for RFS (3), then RSS is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain my understanding, however, maybe not correct. Please help to correct my answers.

First, RPS and RSS work as the same, that is mapping irq/packet to a specific CPU core via hashing, e.g., 4-tuple, V(X)LAN tag and etc. The difference is that RPS is implemented on software, while RSS is implemented on hardware, i.e., NIC.
So the claim in this blog (http://balodeamit.blogspot.ru/2013/10/receive-side-scaling-and-receive-packet.html) may be contract with itself.

Second, RFS and aRFS also perform CPU steering. They map irq/packet to the same core as the upper layer application to achieve affinity, e.g., processed by the same NUMA node. aRFS is the hardware version of RFS. You can refer to this paper (https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3452296.3472888) for more details.

In concolusion, the hard and soft irq may be mapped to the same CPU cores, however, with different steering mechanisms, e.g., RPS/RSS and RFS/aRFS.